# How to prevent tabs from being switched with the arrows?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program that you need to move somthing with the arrows while a tab control is open, but everytime you move it the tabs switch. I tried changing tabStop to false but it doesn't wrok. Is there any way to prevent the tabs from being switched?

Comment: Just to be clear, is it a WinForms or a WPF project?

Answer (score 0):

You must insert into the KeyDown event of each control the verify for codes equal VbDownArrowKey.  See here how to do it:
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets10p3.html